# Do two circles always have a radical axis?

Tags: analytic-geometry, circles

Do two circles always have a radical axis?

---

I came across this question in my book.I think every pair of circles have a radical axis,but my book answer says **NO**,not every pair of circles have a radical axis.
Can someone please elaborate with example which two circles do not have a radical axis associated with them.Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Concentric circles do not have a associated radical axis. One way to think about why this is the case stems from the fact that the configuration has radial symmetry, but a radical axis is a line, hence it does not have radial symmetry. Hence a radical axis does not exist.

If two circles in general position intersect, the radical axis is the line joining the points of intersection.

Here is a proof for concentric circles of different sizes.

Let $P$ be a point on the radical axis outside the circles. It follows that the tangents from $P$ to the circles would be the same length.

Let $O$ be the center of these circles. $OP^2=r_1^2+l^2=r_2^2+l^2$, where $r_1, r_2$ are the radius of the circle and $l$ is the length of the tangent.

As we assumed $r_1\neq r_2$, it follows that there is no solution, i.e. there is no radical axis which lies outside the circles.

Comment: Then could there be a "radical circle" that lies between the two concentric circles? Because afaik, the power is defined also for points lying inside the circle.

Comment: If the point is between the 2 circles, one power is positive while the other is negative.

Comment: @Element118 What if one circle is contained within the other, but they are not concentric, will they have a radical axis? Like $(x-1)^2+y^2=4^2$ and $x^2+y^2=1^2$

Comment: Yes. Your example has the radical axis being $x=-7$.

Comment: @Element118 I would say that two concentric but not congruent circles do not have radical axis, but two concentric and congruent have infinitely many. Can you please share your thoughts on this?

Comment: @ivankokan It all boils down to your definition of radical axis. With the definition of the set of points with the same power of a point with respect to both circles, your "radical axis" is the entire plane. If you define radical axis as any line with every point on it the same power of a point with respect to both circles, then there would be infinitely many such lines. Whichever definition is more useful here depends on the problem considered.

Comment: @Element118 I think we agree on that. Just wanted to point out that case is missing in the answer, and its answer depends on the radical axis definition as you mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

The equation of radical axis of a pair of circles is given by $S-S'=0$.

For concentric circles we will get $S-S'= constant$ instead of line equations. Hence we can conclude that all pair of circles wont necessarily have a radical axis.